# Obtain parameter types of an array of functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make kind of a composer functionality based on an array of functions.
The idea is:

Assuming there exists two closure function `func1` and `func2` both with the same number of arguments that return the same function contract, let's say:
`func1(arg1: {a: number}) => (a: number) => number`
`func2(arg1: {b: string}) => (a: number) => number`

Now, the composer function is like:

```
  const composedFunction = compose({func1, func2});
```

The result of composedFunction is a function with an argument which let configure optionally the arguments to be passed to each function.

```
// ---------------------------- ∨ This is the value passed to the most inner function
const result = composedFunction(33, {func1: {a: 1}});
// --------------------------------- ∧ This is an object with the configuration of each function
```

Where the `result` variable will contain the composition of the result of each function. For clarity, lets say that

```
  const f1 = func1(...);
  const f2 = func2(...);
  // result will be f1(f2(33))
```

**What have I achieved so far**

```
type MyFunction = (value: any) => (a: number) => number;

export const compose = <T extends keyof any>(funcs: Record<T, MyFunction>) => {
  ...
  return (
    value: number,
    config?: Partial<{ [K in keyof typeof funcs]: Parameters<typeof funcs[T]>[0] }>,
  ) => {
    ...
  };
};
```

However, typescript says that for each function the configuration has a value of `any`.

```
const result = composedFunction(33, {func1: {a: 1}});
// --------------------------------- ∧ This configuration results in Partial<{ func1: any, func2: any}>
```

Any ideas on how to make the types of each function arguments appear on the configuration argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would fix it:

```
export const compose = <T extends Record<string, MyFunction>>(funcs: T) => {
  
  return (
    value: number,
    config?: Partial<{ [K in keyof T]: Parameters<T[K]>[0] }>,
  ) => {
    
  };
};
```

You only used `T` to infer the keys of the passed object. Any information about the functions passed is lost since you don't store it anywhere. When you use `Parameters<typeof funcs[T]>[0]`, you will only get `any` as a result since the type of `funcs` is just `Record<"func1" | "func2", MyFunction>` which contains no information about the specfic functions you passed.

You should instead use `T` to infer the whole object with both the keys and the functions. When you use `Parameters<T[K]>[0]` now, `T` contains all the information about the functions.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATBQDMFcDsGMBcCWB7awpwIwAoCGAnAc0wC5gBvXM6SAWwCMBTfAXwEoLQR9H5J80eanSb4OAXgB8FHnwHAADC1AswGBCjTqATHiKkK9MgGd4%20RNELtO3Xv0FVgNBswnTys%204uWrQoeACeAA6MwACyAQBiMBqowOLA2ABuuAA2kIxkuNABbomOzqJ5hcwA3H6MAB5ByPjwwLCopg3ItDXGoQkAPAAqwFXwjNAAJsbAAEqMjfjDXabmlgA04VExSKiSktjqxmQ9eeRcYLZygkcgKemZTiLMi%20ct0OCIhAD8ZAAKBEhpXeTAAG0ANLACzAADWjACyHAwB6AF1PgRcLReMxjL1gfDJACFPDgCxJPcQAcHkcWOUKX5GtBmo02sgOsNonB1mgEvT2oxsOR1Jhljp2OVQDTmjxjJBUvUOa0ucy1ppsABmJXLXkxAyUMiYFhC0BAA)